# Wild characters within jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently started working on a new project with in my firm. Instantly I started observing something unique in all the JavaScript files. I see code something like this

```
$('#alert'/*, target*/).removeClass('info warning success').addClass('danger');
```

I would have totally understood if it was something like this

```
$('#alert', target).removeClass('info warning success').addClass('danger');
```

Comment: Its a comment. Not part of the selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just a [multiline comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Comments) and is ignored

```
$('#alert'/*, target*/)
```

is same as

```
$('#alert')
```

I've seen many developers do this to test out something. Rather than deleting it, they keep it for future reference.

Also, in this example as ID are unique, there is no need of passing context to the selector.

Comment: I would hate to look for an ID element within a target, just saying.. it's just bad code..

Comment: Appears, that some developers don't know of a better place to leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

`/* */` & `//` is use to comment code in javascript

In jquery the wild character(close enough) is like this

```
$("[id^=some_common_prefix]")


$("[id$=some_common_suffix]")
```

where `id` is the `id` attribute